# Select most recent rows for each id

Tags: mysql

I have below two tables one is master table and second is details table.
I need most recent rows from details table ,if details table don't have detail for respective row then it should show blank rows and master table information for that id.

I used below query but its not giving desired output

```
select st.Station_Id,st.id,st.StationType,st.stationname,st.Latitude,st.Longitude, max  (pump.LastUpdate)
```

as LastUpdate,pump.daily_abstraction,pump.water_level from sgwebdb.stations as st 
left outer join sgwebdb.pump_station_data as pump on st.station_id = pump.station_id 
where st.DeletionDate is null and st.stationtype = 'pump station'
group by st.station_id;

Master Table- Stations

ID    Station_ID  StationType   StationName  Lattitude Longitude

1      Pump0       Pump Station   ABC         5.555     100.4578
2      Pump1       Pump Station   DEF         5.555     100.4578
3      Pump2       Pump Station   GHI         5.555     100.4578
4      Pump3       Pump Station   JKL         5.555     100.4578
5      Pump4       Pump Station   MNO         5.555     100.4578
6      Pump5       Pump Station   PQR         5.555     100.4578
7      Pump6       Pump Station   STU         5.555     100.4578
8      Pump7       Pump Station   VXY         5.555     100.4578
9      Pump8       Pump Station   ZAB         5.555     100.4578
10     Pump9       Pump Station   CDE         5.555     100.4578
11     Pump10       Pump Station  FGH         5.555     100.4578
12     Pump11       Pump Station  IJK         5.555     100.4578
13     Pump12       Pump Station  LMN         5.555     100.4578
14     Pump13       Pump Station  OPR         5.555     100.4578
15     Pump14       Pump Station  QST         5.555     100.4578
16     Pump15       Pump Station  UVW         5.555     100.4578

Detail Table Name : pump_station_data`

```
id    Station_id    lastupdate      hrl_abst daily_abst Water_Level
3   Pump15  2014-05-13 12:45:00 23  45      8
4   Pump0   2014-05-20 01:01:00 1   1       1
5   Pump0   2014-07-02 12:00:00 15.41   15.41       51.95
6   Pump0   2014-07-03 12:00:00 0.9 21.6        26.65
7   Pump1   2014-07-03 01:30:00 0   0       21.69
8   Pump0   2014-07-05 09:20:00 20  20      26.7535
9   Pump1   2014-07-05 11:25:00 20  20      21.69
10  Pump2   2014-07-05 15:10:00 20  20      9.4287
11  Pump3   2014-07-05 15:45:00 20  20      6.2608
12  Pump4   2014-07-05 13:25:00 20  20      2.2636
13  Pump5   2014-07-05 16:31:00 20  20      2.2832
14  Pump6   2014-07-05 16:38:00 20  20      2.1249
15  Pump7   2014-07-05 17:35:00 20  20      10
16  Pump8   2014-07-05 17:35:00 20  20      10
17  Pump9   2014-07-05 19:36:00 20  20      2.0994
18  Pump10  2014-07-05 19:55:00 20  20      2.112
19  Pump11  2014-07-05 20:15:00 20  20      2.1054
20  Pump12  2014-07-05 19:45:00 20  20      2.099
21  Pump13  2014-07-05 18:45:00 20  20      2.0994
22  Pump14  2014-07-05 16:45:00 20  20      10
23  Pump15  2014-07-05 16:45:00 20  20      2.1234
24  Pump16  2014-07-05 19:45:00 20  20      10
25  Pump17  2014-07-05 18:25:00 20  20      52.5678
26  Pump18  2014-07-05 18:50:00 20  20      42.0116
27  Pump19  2014-07-05 14:20:00 20  20      10
```

Comment: Please learn to edit questions in good format, so that more people would willing to answer it, the format stackoverflow use is poor yet simple to use.

Comment: @flybird I fomat it properly but after submitting all the format gone away and it came in weird format.

Comment: sometime I think stackoverflow could improve the editor too.

Comment: @flybird yes absolutely correct ,this editor is giving a lot of problems....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this sql:

```
select * from pump_station_data
where id in  (
    select max(id) from pump_station_data group by Station_id
)
order by Station_id;
```

For you second request, try this:
I assume your master table as "station", column name of station id in that table is "Station_id",

```
select psd.*, st.Station_id from pump_station_data as psd
right join station as st
on psd.Station_id = st.Station_id
where psd.id in  (
    select max(id) from pump_station_data group by Station_id
)
order by st.Station_id;
```

Comment: ,thx for query it is working.i need one more thing,i have one master table for station from where I need to join query.basically that is master table for stations.so if any pump station don't have value in above table then it will take master details from stations table and show the blank rows.can we do it?

Comment: @vim Yes, I think so, you can do it by sql or by program, if by sql check the updated answer, the basic idea is to use right join, which will select any row in the right table - Station.

Comment: ,it is giving error near to "right" key word.saying that unexpected right and expecting END_OF_Input

Comment: @vim what database are you using?

Comment: @Vim my mistake, the join clause should be before where clause, try the updated sql.